# Remove whitespace after disabled control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have small page, it looks follows:

Some header

Label with text only for logged users

Hyperlink

Logout button

Here is the behind code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (User.Identity.Name == "")
    {
        Label1.Visible = false;
        Controls.Remove(Label1);
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Question is: When non logged user loads page, the label is not shown. But how to move the hyperlink and logOutButton and thus hide the white space on place, where the label is invisible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the css display:none here

Comment: Label1.Style.Add("display", "none");

Comment: ok...This won't work. I didn't observer that you are actually removing the label from controls.

Comment: It makes the same effect as Label1.visible = false;  The label is hidden, but on it's place is whitespace

Comment: I removed the line Controls.Remove(Label1);

Comment: Are you placing these 3 controls in 3 different tds(table cells)?  Can you post the html of these 3 controls(Use developer tools to extract the html)

Comment: I know the trick with table, but there aren't any cells, it's just controls mentioned above, separated with <br /> tags

Comment: I want to know, how to move hyperlink onto label and logOutButton onto hyperlink (of course, when user is logged, means that invisible label provide free space)

Comment: ok...Then you have to remove the <br> tag below the label that you are hiding

Comment: Wrap your Label and <br> tag in a container may be a panel, and show or hide this panel depending on user login status.

Comment: Wow you helped me a lot. I removed <br /> after label and instead inserted it at the label's end. So when user is logged in, hyperlink is two lines under label, when not, hyperlink moves onto label place. Thanks for your patience ;D

Comment: It looks this    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="pokud jses admin, uvidis kamose :D <br /> <br />" ></asp:Label>

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an Authentication Panel it's a asp:Panel extended and it will able you control "Logged and non Logged user without any headache".

example:

```
public class AuthenticatedPanel : Panel
{
        public string Action { get; set; }

        public AuthenticatedPanel()
        {
            this.Load += new EventHandler(AuthenticatedPanel_Load);
        }

        void AuthenticatedPanel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             //your logic to check wether is user is legit or not 
             // and then 
             this.Visible = false;  
        }
 }
```

//then using

```
<asp:AuthenticatedPanel ID="pnl" runat="server">
  your content here
</asp:AuthenticatedPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

In summary, per the information above and some research, here's what worked for me.  The white space IS removed by using button.Visible = false in codebehind but the "br" tags are remaining, so wrap them inside individual panels and hide the panel, not the button, i.e. panel.Visible = false and it will remove all the white space.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example, on the .aspx page, create a panel with a control inside(notice the "br" tag inside it):

```
<asp:Panel ID="panel" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="button" runat="server"/>
    <br />
</asp:Panel>
```

next, on codeBehind, hide the panel instead of the button:

```
panel.Visible = false;
```